# jQuery function will not return true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small validation script which is working fine. The very end of the script denotes that it should return `true` if it has been successful. I have tested the script and it is reaching this point, but it is not returning `true`

http://jsfiddle.net/5ycpdaja/

```
function validate(id){
    // checks only inputs with type "text" inside div id-calc
    // e.g #haveprice-calc or #dontknow-calc
    var div = $("." + id + "-calc");
    $(div).find("input[type = 'text']").each(function() {
        if(this.value == ""){
            $(this).addClass("errorInput");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("errorInput");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I've tested with a `console.log` and it is getting to the `else` statement just fine, but when I look at the place it was called, it won't return `true`

It should assign the result of `validate` to the variable `valid` - but this appears to always be `undefined`

```
$(".btnCalc").click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var valid = validate(id);
    console.log(valid); // this always shows as undefined, even if the validation scrip was successful
    if (valid == true){
        console.log("validated!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your anonymous function returns true. `validate()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The return statement is in the wrong function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually do a more global variable as jQuery itself is a function, so it has a return value itself:

```
function validate(id){
    var div = $("." + id + "-calc");

    // set up a default return value
    var success = true;

    $(div).find("input[type = 'text']").each(function() {
        if(this.value == ""){
            $(this).addClass("errorInput");
            // instead of returning, set the value here
            success = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("errorInput");
        }
    });

    // return the value. Now your function will return the state of the value at that point.
    return success;
}
```

The `undefined` definition is correct, as your wrapper function does not return anything to the caller.

#### Update

I reversed the function as @bux (and @Francesca) suggested

Comment: I'm guessing it should only return true if all fields are valid. So I reckon `success` should default to `true` and be set to `false` in the first part of the if.

Comment: @bux yeah thats probably true. I did not really go for the actual functionality, but for the concept of returning values. Modifying is always possible :)

Comment: This works perfectly. I've added in @bux 's tweak too. Thanks for the explanation about where I was going wrong.

Comment: @somethinghere you reversed the success var declaration but you still need to move the success = false into the first if section :)

Comment: Damn I was again not looking at the context but the functionality -_- will reverse it some more. Thank @Francesca